# Arraylist is null check in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I am getting first time `arraylist` is `null` but i am checking this if arraylist is empty or not but app is crashed.

this arraylist is in my adapter `workerAdapter.getSelectedList();`

Here is my code

```
  btn_update_staff_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<WorkerItem> arrayList = workerAdapter.getSelectedList();

                List<String> chipValues = nacho_text_view.getChipValues();

                if (!arrayList.isEmpty() && arrayList != null) {
                    List<String> emp_id_member = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < chipValues.size(); i++) {

                        String emp_id = arrayList.get(i).getWorker_emp_id();
                        emp_id_member.add(emp_id);
                    }
                } else if (!worker_list_temp.isEmpty()) {
                    List<String> emp_id_member = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < chipValues.size(); i++) {
                        String emp_id = worker_list_temp.get(i).getWorker_emp_id();
                        emp_id_member.add(emp_id);
                    }
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please Select Employee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: first check if the `list != null` then check for empty

Comment: Replace `if (!arrayList.isEmpty() && arrayList != null)` to ` if (arrayList != null && !arrayList.isEmpty())` ..

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.mindwerx.in.Adapter.WorkerAdapter.getSelectedList()' on a null object reference getting this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
if (!arrayList.isEmpty() && arrayList != null) {
```

to

```
if (arrayList != null && !arrayList.isEmpty()) {
```

You want to make sure that the list is not null before you run a method `#isEmpty()` on it.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.mindwerx.in.Adapter.WorkerAdapter.getSelectedList()' on a null object reference getting this error

Comment: it can not goes to this validation it crashes on   List<WorkerItem> arrayList = workerAdapter.getSelectedList(); this line

Comment: @MindWerx the reason your app is crashing is not because the list is null, but the adapter that you're using the list from is null.
What you should do is 
`if (null == workerAdapter) { Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Adapter is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); return; }`

Add this to the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize arraylists before adding data in them

```
List<WorkerItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<WorkerItem>();

        List<String> chipValues = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:
`if (!arrayList.isEmpty() && arrayList != null) {`
if `arrayList` is null then `isEmpty()` call will throw a `NullPointerException` because you're calling the method first before checking if null.

So, do this instead:
`if (arrayList != null && !arrayList.isEmpty() ) {`
This will first check if arrayList is null, if so, then the part after && will not be executed because you already got false for one of the operands of logical and operation.

false and something = false

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference Between Null and empty.
null means the arraylist is not initialized
and isEmpty() is used to check that is there any item is present in array or not.
if the arraylist size is 0 then it return false else true